# Why this Spring MVC controller method can't handle this simple GET AJAX Request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC application and I have some problem trying to retrieve a String value passed by a JQuery AJAX Request.

```
function aggiungiAppunti() {
    console.log("INTO aggiungiAppunti()");
    //alert("INTO aggiungiAppunti()");

    var testoNotaCorrente = $('#notaCorrente').val();

    alert("NOTA CORRENTE: " + testoNotaCorrente);

    var message = 'Sei sicuro di voler salvare questi appunti?';

    mostraConferma(message, function (){
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "aggiungiAppunti",
            data : { 
                'testoNotaCorrente': testoNotaCorrente
            },
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        }).done(function(principal) {
            replaceFragment($('#situazioniDocumentali'),principal);
            inizializzazioneGestioneValidazione();
        }).error(function(error) {
            showErrorMessage("errore");
        }); 
    });

}
```

So, as you can see in the previous code snippet, I have this JavaScript function that perform a GET AJAX Request toward the **aggiungiAppunti** URL passing the **testoNotaCorrente** textual parameter that contain the value of the **testoNotaCorrente** retrieving it from a textview (I have putter an alert to assure that it is correctly valorized, and it is).

Then into a controller class I have declared this method that have to handle the previous AJAX request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/aggiungiAppunti", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String aggiungiAppunti(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, Locale locale, @RequestParam("testoNotaCorrente") String testoNotaCorrente) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("INTO aggiungiAppunti(), testo nota corrente: " +  testoNotaCorrente);

    return "blablabla";
}
```

but when the AJAX request is performed this method is not performed and I obtain this error message in the stacktrace:

```
15:58:48,332 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'testoNotaCorrente' is not present
```

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing in the variable as a POST variable from javascript, but mapping the Java method to look for GET variables.

See the doc for some more information: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMethod.html#enum.constant.summary

What does the request URL look like in your server access log?

Change your JavaScript to put the variable in the URL.

```
$.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "aggiungiAppunti",
            data : { 
                'testoNotaCorrente': testoNotaCorrente
            },
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        })
```

to

```
$.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "aggiungiAppunti?testtoNotaCorrente="+testtoNotacorrente,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        })
```

-Or-

change the Java to use POST instead of GET:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/aggiungiAppunti", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/aggiungiAppunti", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: You are recommending inserting an issue in the call.. get ajax to post spring.. ?

Comment: @Siddharth I don't understand your question. Could you please clarify? I think my point in this answer is they way they were sending variables. They wanted to put them in the URL string, but they used methods normally for POST. Could either fix the Java or fix the JavaScript. 

Cleaning up the ajax

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself deleting these rows from the AJAX request:

```
processData: false,
contentType: false
```

that become:

```
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "aggiungiAppunti",
        data : { 
            'testoNotaCorrente': testoNotaCorrente
        },
        contentType:"application/json"
    }).done(function(principal) {
        replaceFragment($('#situazioniDocumentali'),principal);
        inizializzazioneGestioneValidazione();
    }).error(function(error) {
        showErrorMessage("errore");
    });
```

So it works with my original controller method without doing other changess

Comment: You're right: `processData: false` disables auto conversion of the `data` instance into JSON string. That's why you couldn't get it work initially.

Comment: There is no need for `contentType`. You don't send any content.

Comment: @RomanProshin There is no such automatic conversion. Read the docs.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of passing the param like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "aggiungiAppunti",
        data : { 
            'testoNotaCorrente': testoNotaCorrente
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(function(principal) {
        replaceFragment($('#situazioniDocumentali'),principal);
        inizializzazioneGestioneValidazione();
    }).error(function(error) {
        showErrorMessage("errore");
    });
```

Try this:

url : "aggiungAppunti?testoNotaCorrente=testoNotaCorrente"